# Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected! Assume -R without save to *.rej

Tags: patch

How to ignore previously applied in large hunks in patch but generate *.rej when hunk patch fail.

I tried many options in *patch* command
But it always generate *.rej, However most hunks in *rej already patched

```
patching file include/net/cfg80211.h
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] <= [R] or [n] still generate *.rej
```

Suppose a case of few hunks need patch but most hunks in the patch file was already patched in my project

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I tried *--forward* at *patch* command to skip when an hunk are *reversed or already applied*

but i still generate *.rej.(I did not need *rej but reserved patch FAIL)

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: I have the same issue on a CMake project, sometimes interrupting a build will cause CMake to not be aware of which patches succeeded or not and then the next time the build is run it tries to apply the patches again only to return this. I've bookmarking the question. If I find the solution I can come back and add an answer.